# How come restarting networking does not work on Debian?

Tags: networking, debian

How come restarting networking does not restart eth0 successfully on my server? None of my CentOS virtual machines have this problem.

```
root@living:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:91:00:01
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe91:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9354 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1052796 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:1129902 (1.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:23280 (22.7 KiB)  TX bytes:23280 (22.7 KiB)
root@living:~# service networking restart
Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces ... (warning).
Reconfiguring network interfaces...
[PuTTY disconnects]
root@living:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:23280 (22.7 KiB)  TX bytes:23280 (22.7 KiB)
```

Comment: Do you use Debian 6.0?

Comment: Can you add in the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`. The problem is likely in there.

Comment: Yes, I use Debian 6.0, but the issue was solved. The issue was I had auto-hotswapping eth0 in my interfaces, replacing it by auto eth0 solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
root@machine:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.110
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.1.0
 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

The solution was replacing allow-hotplug by auto. Thanks! :)

Comment: If this is the answer you needed, please accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I had the same problem and changing from allow-hotplug to auto worked for me as well. Does anyone know why? The strange thing is that after restarting the computer it works, but not after restarting only the network service.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that when networking is shut down (to restart), sshd is noticing and closing the connection.  When sshd closes the connection, the pseudo-tty SIGHUPs the shell, along with the programs that were running in it.  This includes `init.d/networking` which is dying before it can start the connection back up again.

Try running `screen` first (so that the shell is not interrupted) or at least `nohup service networking restart` so that the script won't receive SIGHUP and terminate.

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not come back either....

Comment: @chronoz then I guess the message it gave saying that it may not bring some interfaces back again was right.  Post your interfaces file like SmallClanger asked so we can figure out why.  Looking at the script, it looks like all interfaces but loopback are stopped, but only `auto` interfaces will be brought back up (just like at boot).

Comment: It was solved. The issue was I had auto-hotswapping eth0 in my interfaces, replacing it by auto eth0 solved it.